# Flutter Local Notification

Tags: flutter, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to use the flutter local notification package I write my own code I got code from the internet they both give the same result which is nothing no error, no notification appears, there is nothing
here is the code that I'm using right now

```
static final _notification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future _notificationDetails() async {
    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'Channel id',
        'Channel name',
        channelDescription: 'Channel description',
        importance: Importance.max
      ),
      iOS: IOSNotificationDetails()
    );
  }

  static Future showNotification({
    int id =0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payload
  }) async => _notification.show(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      await _notificationDetails(),
      payload: payload
  );
```

Comment: you can refer to this  https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-local-notifications-in-flutter/

Comment: @SamuelOlufemi I did refer to that and did not get any further.